# RequireJs optimization of template script

Tags: requirejs, playframework-2.1

I have some client javascript and scala page template.

I have to init some js stuff in the template (by params provided to template using scala).

But now we try to migrate to requirejs and we don't want to use global variables (like `window.funnyVar`) and we want to do all js stuff in the modules.

So, there is the following problem: how to init stuff in the module by params provided to scala template.

I do it in the following way. In the template code I define new module and pass all params to it:

```
define("templateModule", ["lib/helper"],
  function(helper){
    helper.init(@param);
    return {};
});
```

In the main js file I do all other stuff after the initialization:

```
require(["lib/helper", "templateModule"],
    function(helper, tpl) {
      // do stuff
    }
);
```

It works fine until I run prod mode.

In the prod mode I have the following error:

```
JavaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/gkalabin/app/target/scala-2.10/classes/public/javascripts-min/templateModule.js (No such file or directory)
In module tree:
    main
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**upd** 
Possible solution to switch from module (`define`) to `require`. But may be there are another solutions?

Thank for your attention. Have a good day!

Comment: Are your JavaScripts in app/assets/javascripts?

Comment: @Schleichardt yes, they are